# why is time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"] off by 1 second in php-cli?

Tags: php, time

running php-cli version 7.3.4 on windows, and 7.3.6 on linux, the equation `time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]` seems to be fairly consistently 1 second off.. why? running `php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'` , i get the number 3.X, i expected this to *always* return a number >=4, why do i get 3.x numbers?

```
hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(getrusage()["ru_utime.tv_sec"]);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
int(0)
float(3.1129999160767)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(getrusage()["ru_utime.tv_sec"]);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
int(0)
float(3.3659999370575)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
float(3.3789999485016)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
float(3.664999961853)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
float(3.3450000286102)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'function f(){sleep(4);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);}f();'
float(3.2279999256134)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'function f(){sleep(4);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);}f();'
float(3.0420000553131)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'function f(){sleep(4);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);}f();'
float(3.539999961853)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'function f(){sleep(4);var_dump(time()-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);}f();f();'
float(3.0999999046326)
float(7.0999999046326)
```

Answer (score 0):

.. apparently it's a precision and rounding issue, `$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]` has microsecond precision, and time() is 1000000 times less precise than that, using microtime(true) instead, we get:

```
hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(microtime(true)-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
float(4)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(microtime(true)-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
float(4)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(microtime(true)-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
float(4.0009999275208)

hans@hans-lp17 ~
$ php -r 'sleep(4);var_dump(microtime(true)-$_SERVER["REQUEST_TIME_FLOAT"]);'
float(4.0009999275208)
```

Comment: No: `time()` can be understood as the truncated version of `microtime( TRUE )`. Output both function's results at once and you'll see that. Which is also logical: if `time()` would round up I'd live in the future.

Comment: Think of it as a digital clock without seconds. At `23:59:59` it still displays `23:59`.